# Winforms application GUI windoes change size after users connect to application machine from different resolution

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have Simple `Winforms Application`.
my application running on machine and user connect this machine via `Remote Desktop` or `RAdmin`.
Because the users that connect into this machine connecting with different resolution (every user use it's own resolution) this cause my application to cut and looks shorter (the button is just disappear)
My application size in constant and cannot be changed\resize.
Any idea how to avoid this behavior ? (i didn't add any code because this is simple UI and my question is general) .

Comment: If you expect your application to work on a wide range of resolutions, you should make it resizable. Very few applications need to be fixed size (mostly games with highly customized UIs).

Comment: If you go with fixed size, then it should be as small, as the smallest *supported* by software screen will be. You can clearly indicate *not supporting remote desktop* in specifications of your software. Or provide an alternative: hotkeys for hidden buttons, possibility to see hidden info by some other meaning, etc...

Comment: My application size is 560x760 and the lowest resolution that the users using is 1024x768 and it still hapenning